# Android Activity/Fragment duplicates on orientation change (Kotlin)

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I've realized that when I change orientation on the mainActivity of my app all the logs start getting duplicated, if I do it again they triple, and so on. I'd assume the activity is being created from scratch every time, but since I'm using navhost I don't know how to make it so it doesn't recreate every time. The MainActivity is basically empty (for now) and holds a fragment with ViewModel.

MainActivity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Timber.plant(DebugTree())
        }
        Timber.w("Started")
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)

override fun onSupportNavigateUp() = findNavController(R.id.my_nav_host_fragment).navigateUp()
```

Fragment code:

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.articles_fragment, container, false)

        Timber.w("oncreateview called")
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(ArticlesViewModel::class.java)

        return v
    }
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        Timber.w("onViewCreated called")
        initAdapter()
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    }
```

So what I did is set a Log on each (not all) lifecycle method, and when app starts it prints each one once, if I flip screen it prints twice, then three times, and so on. If I navigate to another fragment and come back it doesn't duplicate... It seems to be mainly on orientation changes. Here is a Logcat example, I only put onStart from Activity and onViewCreated from fragment so it's not so long:

```
W/MainActivity: Started
W/ArticlesFragment: onViewCreated called
W/MainActivity: Started
W/MainActivity: Started
W/ArticlesFragment: onViewCreated called
W/ArticlesFragment: onViewCreated called
W/MainActivity: Started
W/MainActivity: Started
W/MainActivity: Started
W/ArticlesFragment: onViewCreated called
W/ArticlesFragment: onViewCreated called
W/ArticlesFragment: onViewCreated called
```

So every time I change orientation one instance gets added. And I believe there are actually three instances running on top of each other, and all the methods repeat three times as well. For example, I'm getting data from firestore and when the activity is duplicated data is read twice, or three times if its tripled, etc.

Thanks in advance for any much appreciated help. Cheers!

Comment: From your `MainActivity: Started` calls, it looks like you have multiple instances of your activity (from 1, to 2, to 3). It would be expected that each separate Activity instance would have its own instance of each Fragment. Are you calling `startActivity()` with your `MainActivity` anywhere?

Comment: No, I'm not. My activity class is pretty much what's on the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is having a similar issue, I found what my problem was.

What was really being duplicated was the Timber tree on MainActivity.

Basically this: `Timber.plant(DebugTree())` needs to be surrounded by a null check on savedInstanceState:

```
if (savedInstanceState==null) {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Timber.plant(DebugTree())
        }
 }
```